# Search through logs by author/comitter name in magit log buffer

Tags: magit

Once I enter into the logs for a repo from the status buffer (using <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>) how do I search through the log buffer by username? Just using regular isearch doesn't seem to pick up the author names in the margin. I know I can limit the commits to just a particular user using <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> but I really just want to search through the authors in the margin and see where a certain set of commits by an author are relative to the other commits.

Comment: Magit buffer is just a regular Emacs buffer, so you could do any search you like, in particular, you could do `M-s o` (an alias to `M-x occur`), which would create a new buffer with links to the original Magit log buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting an answer I got from the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/magit/ouCP-kMJXAc):

"If you set ++header in the log buffer, the fields specified by
magit-log-revision-headers-format will be inserted in the log buffer.
Author is included in the default value."

The solution was to essentially ignore the log margin and set the headers with -h, then search through the authors there.